# Is it possible to limit Samba (or entire LAN) speed?

Tags: linux, networking, samba, nfs

I've a problem with a mini server (Via epia c3 1ghz): when there is too much LAN traffic (in particular Samba or NFS files moves) the server reboots and continue to reboot until I unplug the LAN cable or I block the client who is requesting the files.

I don't know why, so I'm guessing: Is there the possibility to limit the speed of Samba or NFS?

Comment: Slowing down the LAN surely isn't the way to fix this! You must find out why the server is rebooting.

Comment: That's kind of like checking your tyres if the car refuses to start.

Comment: How are you determining that its too much LAN traffic?

Comment: do you have any information on the crash? Maybe a trace, dump or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bandwidth limiting incoming](http://www.josefassad.com/iptables_rate_limit_module) traffic on a firewall is difficult because you either have to drop all the unwanted packets - resulting in a resend and more traffic, or have the firewall maintain a delivery queue much larger than its normal connection tracking.

However given that "protecting" the server is more important than traffic shaping you can look at the iptables limit module to limit the number of connections and packets per minute;

```
iptables -A INPUT -p TCP -m state -state NEW \
-m limit -limit 10/minute -limit-burst 2 -j ACCEPT
```

Bear in mind that the upshot of all this is *usually* locking yourself out of the server, or annoying the shit out of everyone.

You might be better off opening another question to trouble shoot the problem causing the crash rather than spending time working out traffic shaping...

Comment: Can something like `trickle` be used? ([ref on SU](http://superuser.com/q/126916/978))